# AngularJS UI.router multiples views in a single page not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

```
.state("home",{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'./resources/js/baseapp/ContactHome/views/ContactHome.html'

})
.state("home.contacts",{
    url:'/home',
    views:{

        "contactByName":{
            templateUrl : './resources/js/baseapp/ContactHome/views/SearchByName.html',
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        },
        "contactByNumber":{
            template:"This is search by Number",
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        },
        "contactByArea":{
            template:"This is search by Area",
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        }


    }
```

})

The state (home.contacts) is which has 3 views is not working,
    not displaying 3 sections , could somebody help me on this 
    Below are the ui-view directives in ContactHome.html

```
<div ui-view="contactByName">  
<div ui-view="contactByNumber"> 
<div ui-view="contactByArea">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definition as a concept should be working. There is [a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUFbWMHZP8OzZF1xq2tI?p=preview)

I a bit adjusted  url of child state to be `'/contacts'` (`/home` is left for *home*)

```
.state("home",{
    url:'/home',
    templateUrl:'resources/js/baseapp/ContactHome/views/ContactHome.html'

})
.state("home.contacts",{
    url:'/contacts',
    views:{

        "contactByName":{
            templateUrl : 'resources/js/baseapp/ContactHome/views/SearchByName.html',
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        },
        "contactByNumber":{
            template:"This is search by Number",
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        },
        "contactByArea":{
            template:"This is search by Area",
            controller:'contactHomeCtrl'
        }   

    }
```

And these links are now working

```
  <a href="#/home">
  <a href="#/home/contacts">
  <a ui-sref="home">
  <a ui-sref="home.contacts">
```

Play with it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tUFbWMHZP8OzZF1xq2tI?p=preview)

Comment: Kohler, Thank u for responding, I could see the working example on the plunker , but I don't need any hyperlinks. in my code I am redirecting path to state "/home" the same time I need to display all the 3 sections which are part of the same view of the state "home". Thanks

Comment: You would need to read more about UI-Router. Every state (even child of parent) needs url (usually). And usually it is different than parent. But if you want to have **one state** with nested views... you should do it like this http://plnkr.co/edit/SJ8lonTlIRnEMqQaGaDU?p=preview (check the @home in view names)